# -makeFirstResponder: usage

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsresponder

I am fairly new to cocoa programming and I would like to ask if anyone can explain me how to 
`-(BOOL)makeFirstResponder:(NSResponder *)responder;` method works. I was planning on using it for `NSEvent` but can anyone show me how to implement it?

I am trying to use the `NSResponder` class to get me a working `-keyDown` method.

Comment: You don't implement it.  You call it when you want something to become First Responder, or the view that has focus.  For example, `[[myTextField window] makeFirstResponder:myTextField]`

Answer (score 3):

NSResponder is one of the fundamental classes in Cocoa. Any class that can respond to events like key presses or menu commands should be a subclass of NSResponder. Each responder keeps track of it's "next responder", and each window keeps track of the object that's currently the "first responder". When an event happens in a window, a message is sent to the first responder. If that object handles the message, great. If not, it passes it along to its next responder. This is known as the "responder chain."

Normally, you don't mess much with the responder chain in Cocoa. The first responder is mostly determined by user actions, such as clicking on a control.

It doesn't make sense to 'use it for NSEvent'. NSEvent isn't a responder, but something that enables responders to do their job.

If you describe more clearly what you're trying to accomplish, I'm sure we can point you in the right direction.

Comment: You don't use (call) `becomeFirstResponder` or `resignFirstResponder`; the documentation says for each of them “Use the NSWindow `makeFirstResponder:` method, not this method, to make an object the first responder. Never invoke this method directly.”

Comment: @Peter Hosey, You're quite right! Maybe I've been spending too much time in Cocoa Touch.

Answer (score 2):

You don't usually implement `-makeFirstReponder:`, you call it to set the input focus to a view. What is it that you really want to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

> I am trying to use the NSResponder class to get me a working keyDown method.

That doesn't make sense. “Use” a class?

If you want to respond to key events, you normally should do that in a view that should be capable of becoming the first responder (see [the NSView docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSView_Class/)).

See also the [Event-Handling Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/EventOverview/), the [View Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaViewsGuide/), and the video for session 145 (“Key Event Handling in Cocoa Applications”) from the [WWDC 2010 session videos](http://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2010/) (which you should be able to access through your developer account even if you didn't go to WWDC last year).

Comment: Thanks I think this would work! I was trying this because on another forum they said I needed to use the NSResponder class, to get the keyDown method to work.